# Ember- update a model using updateRecord with values coming from the controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my signup.js route, I'm using the code below to fetch values from my signup.js controller, and then save a new record on the user model. It works fine.

```js
actions: {
  save: function() {
    var userName = self.controller.get('userName');
    var userEmail = self.controller.get('userEmail');
    var userHeight = self.controller.get('userHeight');

    var user = this.store.createRecord('user', {
      name: userName,
      email: userEmail,
      info: {
        height: userHeight,
      },
    });
    user.save();
  },
}
```

Now I need to update the record from the edit-account.js route. The values coming from the controller will have been updated by the end user.

The additional field 'securityToken' needs to be included for security reasons (The end user must also fill this in).

```js
actions: {
  save: function() {
    var user = this.get('model.user');
    var userEmail = self.controller.get('userEmail');
    var userHeight = self.controller.get('userHeight');
    var securityToken = self.controller.get('securityToken');
    
    this.store.updateRecord('user', {
      name: userName,
      email: userEmail,
      info: {
        height: userHeight,
      },
      confirm_user: securityToken,
    });
    user.save();
  },
}
```

I can't work out the correct way of doing this- I've tried many variations on the above, but they all give the error 'store is not defined'.

Is it possible to update an existing record with this kind of pattern?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to access the store in a component? Which ember version are you using?

Comment: Ember 1.13. This code is not in a component- I'm trying to access the store from the edit-account route.

Comment: routes have `store` service accessible to them. Are you sure you aren't overwriting it somewhere by accident? Your code presented here is fine.

Comment: I don't think so- at the moment this is the only code in my route.